# GENEXUS Problemas con SD Android Send() y Receive() After Lapsed Time - No me esta funcionando

Tags: genexus

Estoy con Gx 15 U4 - SD Android - .Net - App Offline - La pantalla siempre está encendida.

Tengo configuradas las propiedades Send() y Receive() cada 120 segundos y sin embargo no se dispara pasados esos 2 minutos.

El caso de uso es el siguiente:

La app siempre está activa, o sea que no está corriendo en *background*.

Actualmente pasa lo siguiente:

1. Abro la App
2. Ingreso una registro y lo manda enseguida
3. Ingreso otro registro y no lo envía como es de esperarse
4. Dejo pasar varios minutos y en forma automática no llega al server..

Una vez que pasaron los 2 minutos, si trato de empezar a hacer otra marca, luego de cierta cantidad de dígitos marcados, la App revisa si el código ingresado es válido, (esta se hace llamando desde la App a un Procedure que consume un BC), ni bien se hace esto, se envían los datos pendientes al Server.

Esta bastante acotado el problema, o se dispara al llamar a un PROC porque retoma como la actividad el sistema. ¿Hay alguna configuración que este mal?

Aún no pruebo solamente llamando a un Proc que no haga nada para saber si influye la llamada al PROC en el envío o es la lectura del BC.

¿Qué solución puedo tener al tema?

La necesidad es que luego del último envío (forzado o automático), el sistema envíe cada 120 segundos automáticamente.

Gracias.

Comment: Cuando dices que "Tengo configuradas las propiedades Send() y Receive() cada 120 segundos", ¿estás hablando de las propiedades **Minimum Time Between Sends** y **Minimum Time Between Receives**? Por la descripción del problema, parece que solo tienes problemas con el Send (envío desde el dispositivo al servidor). ¿Es así?

Comment: Hola Marcos, si, son esas 2 propiedades a las que me refiero. Respecto a tu pregunta, estuve haciendo las pruebas de configurar el Receive y el Send con diferentes intervalos y ninguno esta respondiendo al tiempo especificado en las propiedades.  Lo cierto es que, si transcurrió el tiempo especificado y con un botón que lo único que hace es llamar a un Proc que esta vacío, que no recibe ni siquiera parámetros, los datos van al server sin problema. Gracias por tu respuesta..

Comment: Tenemos reproducido el caso. Se da en Android con el Send() con la propiedad Minimum Time Between Sends configurada. Lo vemos. Gracias